# UserTerritory2Association Object

Tags: territory-management, territory, winter15

I want to rename the label of the field. Can we change the field label for RoleInTerritory2 field in UserTerritory2Association object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible by using VF page. In Standard page is not possible to rename label of the field.